# Партицирование в MySQL, индексы и кэш

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. При партицировании таблиц в кэше в оперативе находится только последняя партиция, а все остальные лежат в "холодном кэше", чтобы не засорять оперативу. Есть таблица:

id (primary)
user_id (index)
.....
date (index)

Если сделать партицироание по полю date за каждые пол года, то получится около 20 партиций. Вопрос:

Данный запрос будет забирать данные из всех партиций в холодном кеше? Ведь user_id присутствует во всех партициях?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl USE INDEX (user_id) WHERE 
          user_id = 1 AND date BETWEEN  "последний месяц"
```

Answer (score 0):

Если диапазон дат, по которому вы делали партиции и по которому вы ищите, приходится только на какие-то партиции, или даже одну партицию, то другие партиции не будут задействованы.

[Подробно в документации.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-pruning.html)